# how can i find the next min number in dictionary list

Tags: python

I want to find the next minimum value of the dictionary  i wrote this code but it seems like there is an error with for loop 
any help ??

```
nodesdistfromsmartmeter = {'nodeA': 100, 'nodeB': 250, 'nodec': 300, 'nodeD': 50}

min_dist=min(nodesdistfromsmartmeter,key=nodesdistfromsmartmeter.get)
print("smalistdist",min_dist)
seondmin=0
for v in nodesdistfromsmartmeter():
 if(v>seondmin and v>min_dist):
    seondmin=v
    print(seondmin)
```

Comment: Next min as in 100 in your example?

Comment: yes it should be 100

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it has some errors fixed.

```
nodesdistfromsmartmeter = {'nodeA': 100, 'nodeB': 250, 'nodec': 300, 'nodeD': 50}

min_dist=min(nodesdistfromsmartmeter,key=nodesdistfromsmartmeter.get)
print("smalistdist",min_dist)
secondmin=0
for v in nodesdistfromsmartmeter.keys():
 if(nodesdistfromsmartmeter[v]>secondmin and nodesdistfromsmartmeter[v]>nodesdistfromsmartmeter[min_dist]):
    secondmin=nodesdistfromsmartmeter[v]
    print(seondmin)
```

Output:

```
smalistdist nodeD
100
250
300
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :

```
from heapq import nsmallest

my_dict = {'nodeA': 100, 'nodeB': 250, 'nodec': 300, 'nodeD': 50}

print(nsmallest(2, my_dict.values())[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this:

```py
for v in nodesdistfromsmartmeter():
```

For this:

```py
for v in nodesdistfromsmartmeter.values():
```

Comment: still gives me an error

Comment: it turned to this error    if(v>seondmin and v>min_dist):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I updated my answer